# scrlttr2 wider folding marks

Tags: margins, koma-script

I want to use folding marks with my `scrlttr2` letters, however my printer margin cuts them off. Thus I want the marks to be a little bit longer/wider so that they reach farther into the document. How can I achieve this?

Here is an example code of my letter.

```
\documentclass[
   paper=a4,
    pagenumber=false, % Removes page numbers from page 2 onwards
    parskip=half, % Separates paragraphs with some whitespace, use parskip=full for more space or comment out to return to default
    fromalign=locationright, % Aligns the from address to the right
    foldmarks=true, % Prints small fold marks on the left of the page
    addrfield=true 
    ]{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{date}{\today} % Date of the letter
 \begin{document}
 \begin{letter}{Recipient\\somestreet 15\\12345 postalcode} % Addressee name and address
\opening{To whom it may concern}
This is a letter body.
\closing{yours sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please keep you example to the necessary commands, called Minimal Working Example. You set variables to their default or set variables that are not being of effect here. You can replace the whole block above `\begin{document}` with `\documentclass{scrlttr2}` without altering the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following chapter 22.1 in the documentation of KOMA-Script (German version, open it with `texdoc koma-script`) you can use the command `\@setplength` to change the value of the relevant pseudolength `foldmarkhpos`.  Because there is a `@`used in the command you need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Please see the following MWE (changed code marked with `<==========`)

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4,
  pagenumber=false, % Removes page numbers from page 2 onwards
  parskip=half, % Separates paragraphs with some whitespace, use parskip=full for more space or comment out to return to default
  fromalign=locationright, % Aligns the from address to the right
  foldmarks=true, % Prints small fold marks on the left of the page
  addrfield=true,
]{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{date}{\today} % Date of the letter

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\@setplength{foldmarkhpos}{1cm} % 3,5 mm % \@setplength[Faktor]{Pseudolänge}{Wert}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Recipient\\somestreet 15\\12345 postalcode} % Addressee name and address
\opening{To whom it may concern}
This is a letter body.
\closing{yours sincerely}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Change the value `1cm` to that what you need ...

If you are using an own `lco` file (as I do) you can add the command there (without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

---

**EDIT**

Meanwhile (since version [3.26.2980](https://komascript.de/release3.26), ~ since 2019) there is the "userspace"-command `\setplength` so that this solution reduces to:

```
\setplength{foldmarkhpos}{1cm}
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to [Mensch's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332374/37806), I would like the answer the actual question being asked: *How can I widen the foldmarks?*

This is described in section 22.1.1, p. 498ff of the [KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf).
There are three separate variables for the three fold marks you mention (top, paper, bottom), that can be set using:

```
\setplength{tfoldmarklength}{2mm}
\setplength{pfoldmarklength}{4mm}
\setplength{bfoldmarklength}{2mm}
```

Additionally there is the aforementioned horizontal distance to the left paper margin

```
\setplength{foldmarkhpos}{3.5mm}
```

as well as the fold mark thickness:

```
\setplength{foldmarkthickness}{.2pt}
```

You could hence set:

```
\setplength{tfoldmarklength}{4mm}
\setplength{pfoldmarklength}{8mm}
\setplength{bfoldmarklength}{4mm}
\setplength{foldmarkthickness}{.5pt}
```

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\begin{document}
  \setplength{tfoldmarklength}{4mm}
  \setplength{pfoldmarklength}{8mm}
  \setplength{bfoldmarklength}{4mm}
  \setplength{foldmarkthickness}{.5pt}
  \begin{letter}{Recipient\\somestreet 15\\12345 postalcode}
    \opening{To whom it may concern}
    This is a letter body.
    \closing{yours sincerely}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```